# Accidentally deleted a row within the core_store table within my database and now it's break

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, error

Accidentally deleted a row within the core_store table within my database and now I don't have access to my admin or the main website!

Here is the error code which shows up when I try to access either of them:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on null in /Magento/Website_Name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 722**

Here is the code on line 722:

`return $this->_stores[$this->_groups[$group]->getDefaultStoreId()]->getCode();`

I had a copy fo the sql file for that particular table and I have reinserted the row again, but it won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need this website back up and running as soon as possible!

Comment: Check the `core_store_group` table to make sure there is a corresponding entry that references your data in `core_store`

Comment: I managed to gain access but deleting the cache manually using FTP, as I'd checked the core_store & core_store_group & core_store_website relations and they matched up perfectly. But after deleting the ache I will need to amend fix some stuff.

Comment: Do you have any old copies of the database. The core_store table does not change often so you can probably just import a dump of that specific table and your issue should be fixed.

Comment: Hey Shawn, I have already uploaded the previous relations I believe were the culprit,(core_store, core_store_group & core_website), and have gained access back to my admin, along with my website. The issue now is that the website won't load from the header down, with the content not even placed within the main-container or footer. Any ideas what it could be?